# $f$ ia continuously differentiable function with $f'(c)=0$.............................

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-writing

Let $f$ be a continuously differentiable  function  on  $[a,b].$  There is a number $c$ in  $(a,b]$ such that  $f'(c)=0.$ Then prove that there is a fixed number $\xi\in(a,b)$ such that $$f'(\xi)={{f(\xi)-f(b)}\over {b-a}}.$$

How do I begin it , just give me some hints please .

Comment: Is the numerator $f(\xi)-f(b)$ or $f(\xi) - f(a)$?

Comment: It must be $f(\xi)-f(a)$, as otherwise, I believe, $f(x)=x^3,a=-1,b=1$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Or, it can be $f(b) - f(\xi)$.

Comment: @jameselmore : Tthe question paper says $f(\xi)-f(b)$ .

Answer (score 0):

As Wojowu has pointed out, the question, as written, is false.  The counterexample is, $f(x)=x^3,a=−1,b=1$.  Then clearly, $f'(0) = 0$ for $0\in[-1, 1]$; however, $$f'(\zeta)=\frac{f(\zeta)-f(b)}{b-a}\mathrm{\ becomes\ }3\zeta^2 = \frac{\zeta^3-1}{1-^-1}$$ or $\zeta^3-6\zeta^2-1=0$.  This has no solutions in [-1, 1].

My interpretation of the question is, if you meant $$f'(\zeta)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

First, modify $g(x) = f(x) - f(a) + \frac{x-a}{b-a}(f(a)-f(b))$.  (possibly something very similar, depending on the exact statement of the question, as discussed in the comments).

Then $g(a) = 0 = g(b)$, and you are looking for a number so that $g'(\xi) = 0$.  Since $g$ is also continuously differentiable, then there is a theorem that you can use to tell you that.

Comment: $g'(x)=f'(x)+{{f(a)-f(b)}\over {b-a}}$ . So, for some $\xi$ when $g'(\xi)=0$ we have $$f'(\xi)={{f(b)-f(a)}\over {b-a}}$ . This is the exact function we used to prove the MVT.

Comment: So, I updated my question to reflect Wojowu's comment that the claim, as stated, is false.  Please correct the claim, and then I can look to see how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the second statement is not true. Take the the identity, then the equation becomes $$1=\frac{\xi-b}{b-a}$$ which is impossible since because the right side is negative.

If we change the -f(b) to a -f(a) then this is still not true, because for the identity the equation holds iff $\xi = b$

Comment: I think you misunderstood  my  question .  It does not require every  continuously differentiable  function to have a $c$ s.t. $f'(c)=0$ .  It gives two hypotheses : $1)$ continuously diff. and $2)$ $f'(c)=0$  for some $c$.  Using these two we have to prove that  last equality.

Comment: oh yes you are right. But I don't see how to make this statement correct...